# How to restore a Postgres dump in kubernetes?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, restore, pg-dump

have taken a Postgres dump using the below script and it was successful in k8.

```
kubectl -n [namespace] exec -it [pod name] -- bash -c "export PGPASSWORD='[db password]'; pg_dump -U [db user] [db name]" > [database].sql
```

what is the equivalent command to restore the same dump in kubernetes?

Comment: As you created a SQL dump, you need to use `psql` to execute that SQL script

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, it worked with psql, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to restore the dump, you simply use `psql`:

```
kubectl -n [namespace] exec -it [pod name] -- bash -c "export PGPASSWORD='[db password]'; psql -U [db user] [new db name] -f [database].sql"
```

Comment: yes, have amended the below script as per the sql dup and it is working. Thanks.

kubectl -n [namespace] exec -it [pod name] -- bash -c "export PGPASSWORD='[db password]'; psql -U [db user] [db name]" < [database].sql